# Does "merge" mean "concatenate" or "largest" when determining the length of GAS's .comm symbol if it appears in two object files?

Tags: assembly, symbols, ld, gnu-assembler

I have difficulty in understanding the length of common symbol based on this online document on GNU AS: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Comm.html#Comm. It says if a common symbol appears in two object files, it will be *merged*. I got confused what the "merged" length of this common symbol would be. For example, if I write a line in `file1.S`:

```
.comm stack, 1024
```

If I write the same line in `file2.S`, would the common symbol `stack` be allocated 2048 bytes (i.e., concatenate), or 1024 bytes (i.e. largest, according to this quote from the doc)?

> ..., it will allocate space using the largest size.

The platform I am working on is Linux on an i386 compatible CPU. Please let me know if you need any other information of my platform to determine what the "merged" length means.

Comment: Did you try it?  Should be easy enough to tell with `size a.out` or `readelf -a a.out`, especially if you use a larger size like 64k that's more than the page size.

Comment: Yes, as the manual says, “merged” means that one block is allocated using the largest size of all blocks with that name.